# C++ Reversing Order of Values in a Vector without the use of a reverse iterator

Tags: c++

Read integers from input and store each integer into a vector until 0 is read. Do not store 0 into the vector. Then, output all values in the vector in reverse order, each on a new line.

This is the current code I used and for some reason it only outputs 2 or 3 values instead of all of them. Is there something I did wrong?

```
int main() {
    unsigned int i;
    int inputNum;
    vector<int> vectorNum;

    cin >> inputNum;

    while (inputNum != 0) {
        vectorNum.push_back(inputNum);
        cin >> inputNum;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < vectorNum.size(); ++i) {
        cout << vectorNum.back() << endl;
        vectorNum.pop_back();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < vectorNum.size(); ++i)` -- while `i` is increasing, the size of the vector is decreasing.  You are burning the candle at both ends.

Comment: do you mean "without using a reverse iterator" ? What is wrong with reverse iterator? In any case you can use a normal iterator and decrement it if you are careful with the counts.

Comment: Do NOT change the content of a vector while iterating over it. You could use `std::reverse(vectorNum.begin(), vectorNum.end())` if you don't mind changing the content of your vector first, or you can use `for(const auto& value : vectorNum | std::views::reverse)`  (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view) to only iterate reversly

Comment: I fixed the title assuming you mean reverse iterators. Though you should still clarify why you dont want to use reverse iterators. And in case you didnt mean reverse iterators you should clarify as well ;)

Comment: `for (unsigned i = vec.size(); i > 0; --i) std::cout << vectorNum[i-1] << '\n';`.

Comment: `for (auto i = vec.size(); i-- > 0;) std::cout << vectorNum[i] << '\n';`

Comment: the reason I didn't want to use a reverse iterator was because I hadn't learned it in homework yet. Thank you for all the help and comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this:

```
for (i = 0; i < vectorNum.size(); ++i) {
  cout << vectorNum.back() << endl;     
  vectorNum.pop_back();
}
```

the issue is that you are increasing `i` in the `for` loop, but decreasing the number of entries in the vector with `pop_back()`.  Both things occurring will result in less items processed.

Instead of a `for` loop, use `while()` and the `empty()` member function:

```
while (!vectorNum.empty())
{
   cout << vectorNum.back() << endl;    
   vectorNum.pop_back();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While PaulMcKenzie is [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77904271/15261315), it's worth pointing out that the problem description doesn't actually call for *modifying* the vector at all. Then we just need to count up from zero and do a little math to get indexes in reverse order.

```
using size_t = std::vector<int>::size_type;

size_t sz = vectorNum.size();

for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
    std::cout << vectorNum[sz - 1 - i] << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, it might be interesting to know what problem exists with using reverse iterators, because this is even simpler with them.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::copy(
        v.rbegin(), v.rend(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")
    );
}
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```